# Fast way to save lines from coordinate groupings in R

Tags: r, dplyr, data.table, geospatial, r-sf

I'm generating paths from jogging coordinates. A sample like what I have can be reproduced below:

```
#Reproduce Data
library(data.table)
library(sf)
dt <- data.table(lon=sample(c(380:390), 1000000, replace = TRUE)/10,lat=sample(c(80:90), 1000000, replace = TRUE)/10, pgrp=rep(c(1:100),10000))
tpathline <- st_as_sf(dt, coords = c("lon","lat"),crs=4326)
```

The below to compile the points in groups of lines takes FOREVER. I have a bunch of these to do, is there a faster/better way to compile lines than the dplyr pipe below?

```
#Works but slowest thing ever
library(dplyr)
baseline <- tpathline %>%
  dplyr::group_by(pgrp) %>%
  dplyr::summarise(do_union=F) %>%
  sf::st_cast("MULTILINESTRING")
```

Thanks in advance!!!

Answer (score 2):

This is my general approach when working with `sf` and `data.table`, and it's pretty quick too.

```
library(data.table)
library(sf)
dt <- data.table(lon=sample(c(380:390), 1000000, replace = TRUE)/10,lat=sample(c(80:90), 1000000, replace = TRUE)/10, pgrp=rep(c(1:100),10000))

sf <- dt[
    , {
        geometry <- sf::st_linestring(x = matrix(c(lon, lat), ncol = 2))
        geometry <- sf::st_sfc(geometry)
        geometry <- sf::st_sf(geometry = geometry)
    }
    , by = pgrp
]

sf <- sf::st_as_sf(sf)
```

As you're creating LINESTRINGs this assumes your data is ordered.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this?

```
library(data.table)
library(sf)
dt <- data.table(lon=sample(c(380:390), 1000000, replace = TRUE)/10,lat=sample(c(80:90), 1000000, replace = TRUE)/10, pgrp=rep(c(1:100),10000))

tpathline <- data.table(st_as_sf(dt, coords = c("lon","lat"),crs=4326))

lns = st_as_sf(tpathline[, list(geometry = st_cast(st_union(geometry), "LINESTRING")), by = pgrp])
```

Comment: I think there might be an error in here somewhere, as `lns[['geometry']][[1]] == lns[['geometry']][[2]]` gives `[1] TRUE` - i.e., all your lines are the same

Comment: Thanks @SymbolixAU! You are right. Your answer seems to be the right approach to this.